# passing parameters from php to python incomplete

Tags: php, python

I'm having a problem on passing the parameters from php to python.

By using the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].

```
http://www.domain.com/path?a_num=123&msg=hello
```

i will put the **a_num=123&msg=hello** to a variable

```
$a = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
system("python python.py ".$a);
```

and in python will print it

```
a = sys.argv[1]
print a
```

and the result is  ***a_num=123*** only

what is the problem?

Comment: The `&` is cutting off the rest of the string, but I'm not familiar enough with php to know how to rectify that.

Comment: @jmu303 yeah. i think so too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem with PHP, more how the system command is being executed.  Assuming you are using Linux, the '&' character in the command:

```
python python.py a_num=123&msg=hello
```

Is being interpreted as a control operator.  From the documentation for bash (although this applies equally to other shells such as tcsh):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does
>   not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.

To prevent this, you need to quote the string being passed:

```
python python.py "a_num=123&msg=hello"
```

Which in PHP would look like:

```
system("python python.py \"".$a."\"");
```